Issue: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'y0_' not found During High Database Load
I'm encountering an issue where the error java.sql.SQLException: Column 'y0_' not found appears, especially under increased database load. This error is intermittent and seems to correlate with high concurrency or resource contention.
Application Setup:
We have implemented CQRS pattern and these are read heavy application

Deployment: Kubernetes (k8s) pods on AWS-EKS, spread across two
regions.
Scale: Around 40 pods per region, handling about 2000 transactions per second (tps) in each region.
Database: MySQL (AWS-RDS)
Framework: Spring v4.3.x, Hibernate v4.3.x
Connection Pooling: C3P0 v0.9.x

This exception notably arises when we perform a complete failover of one of the regions. Despite extensive investigation, the root cause remains elusive. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or could provide suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Stack trace:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'y0_' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2745)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultRow(CriteriaLoader.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:754)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    ... 26 common frames omitted

